# Passing parameters into a pd.read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Having a query like:

```
data_raw_sql = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT a, Date, c                    
                                 FROM table_d 
                                 where a IN {0} 
                                 AND Date >= "2021-07-25" '''.format(my_tuple), conn
                                 )
```

I would like to be able to pass the Date as a variable.
How to create a read_sql_query so that I can pass multiple variables into it, including formatting a tuple and adding additional variables?

Comment: Create a function that builds the sql query as per your requirement, then call that function from within the read_sql_query, that way the SQL query gets substituted there.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `read_sql_query` should be a string or SQLAlchemy Selectable ([source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)). In your solution, the string is spread across multiple lines, so you should use `triple quote syntax` to wrap a multiline string.

Here is what you can do, also if you need to create a bunch of such queries you should create a function to do this for you. As Teja Goud mentioned.

```
#Define a, Date, c, t (the tuple) and format the query string as following
query = """SELECT {}, {}, {} FROM table_d WHERE a IN {} AND Date >= '2021-07-25'""".format(a, Date, c, t)

data_raw_sql = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```